# Recommended Resource for learning Anchor

Tags: anchor

I am looking into picking up Anchor, and found the [Anchor book](https://book.anchor-lang.com/) but I just saw it is incomplete. Those anyone know a complete resource for learning Anchor that they can recommend?

Edit: Apparently the book is no longer maintained :( The [Github repo](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor-book) has been archived. :(

Answer (score 1):

So far I did not find complete resource for Anchor. Beside book, you will need to search other resources as well. The good starting point is [SolDev page](https://soldev.app/library/tutorials/filter?tag=Anchor) with tutorials provided by Solana community, so probably you should check that and see if anything suits your needs.

Comment: The first link in the SolDev page you shared now leads to 404 https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/getting-started/introduction.html LOL. How come the solana dev ecosystem seems to be in a bad state? :(

Answer (score 0):

[Buildspace](https://buildspace.so/learn-solana) is a great starting point which introduces Solana development with hands-on project and a gentle learning curve.

If you prefer learning from examples, [Anchor By Example](https://examples.anchor-lang.com/) is your go-to resource.